# How can I be sure Two strings have intersection in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

two string split with ',' like this:

**a:'1,2,3,4,5'** 
**b:'6,2,1,3,9'**

I want to be sure these string if have intersection..

have anything function can be deal with it in mysql?

thx!

Comment: [This](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-intersect.html) maybe help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the kind of problems that you get when you fail to normalize your databases.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes! And so it is!

Answer (score -1):

I must stress that just asking the question makes clear that your data structure is wrong.  You should have a table for each of the pairs.  It would have rows like:

```
a    1
a    2
. . .
b    6
b    2
etc.
```

And this question would be easily solved using standard SQL.

That said, if you are forced for some reason to do this, MySQL has some functions that can help.  You can do something like:

```
where find_in_set(substring_index(substring_index(a, ',', 1), ',', -1), a) > 0 or
      find_in_set(substring_index(substring_index(a, ',', 2), ',', -1), a) > 0 or
      find_in_set(substring_index(substring_index(a, ',', 3), ',', -1), a) > 0 or
      find_in_set(substring_index(substring_index(a, ',', 4), ',', -1), a) > 0 or
      find_in_set(substring_index(substring_index(a, ',', 5), ',', -1), a) > 0 or
      . . .
```

The expression `substring_index(substring_index(a, ',', 5), ',', -1)` is a MySQL expression that returns the nth value in a string.

Comment: but these string be decisioned at runtime.mybe '1,2,3' '1,2,3,4,5,6' or '7,4,2,6,7,8' '0,2,4,9'